# Latex equations won't work properly

Tags: jquery, html, dom, latex

```
<form name="checkListForm">
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#button').click(function(){
           var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
           $('.list').append('<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\frac{x}  {y}"/>');

        }); 
         $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
            $(this).remove();
         });
      });
    </script>
```

So I have this form right here that when I press the button should append [this](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7By%7D) latex equation to the html element .list. But insted of that i got [this](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%0Crac%7Bx%7D%7By%7D)
I'm using this lates equation js file form codecogs: codecogs.com/latex/htmlequations.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character in your line:

`$('.list').append('<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\frac{x}{y}"/>');`

So, go ahead and change it to:

`$('.list').append('<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\frac{x}{y}"/>');`

In your version, you are trying to escape the `f` character which is incorrect.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bowlinmaster/TXpLr/)